# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

my application that I was creating was closing by itself, everything was fine, out of nowhere it gave this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke the virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener )' on a null object reference.

I am not able to resolve this error, I have tried everything to try to make it work, however, I am not succeeding.

**HERE MY CODE**

```
package br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.tsuryo.swipeablerv.SwipeLeftRightCallback;
import com.tsuryo.swipeablerv.SwipeableRecyclerView;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.adapter.AdapterProduto;
import br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.autencacao.LoginActivity;
import br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.helper.FirebaseHelper;
import br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.model.Produto;
import br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterProduto.OnClick {

    private AdapterProduto adapterProduto;
    private List<Produto> produtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private SwipeableRecyclerView rvProdutos;
    private TextView text_info;

    private ImageButton ibAdd;
    private ImageButton ibVerMais;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ouvinteCliques();

        configRecyclerView();

        iniciaComponentes();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        recuperaProdutos();
    }

    private void recuperaProdutos() {
        DatabaseReference produtosRef = FirebaseHelper.getDatabaseReference()
                .child("produtos")
                .child(FirebaseHelper.getIdFirebase());
        produtosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                produtoList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Produto produto = snap.getValue(Produto.class);
                    produtoList.add(produto);
                }

                verificaQtdLista();

                Collections.reverse(produtoList);

                adapterProduto.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void ouvinteCliques() {
        ibAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FormProdutoActivity.class));
        });

        ibVerMais.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, ibVerMais);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, popupMenu.getMenu());

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItem -> {
                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sobre) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Sobre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sair) {
                    FirebaseHelper.getAuth().signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                }
                return true;
            });

            popupMenu.show();

        });
    }

    private void configRecyclerView() {


        rvProdutos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvProdutos.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapterProduto = new AdapterProduto(produtoList, this);
        rvProdutos.setAdapter(adapterProduto);

        rvProdutos.setListener(new SwipeLeftRightCallback.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwipedLeft(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipedRight(int position) {

                Produto produto = produtoList.get(position);


                produtoList.remove(produto);
                produto.deletaProduto();
                adapterProduto.notifyItemRemoved(position);

                verificaQtdLista();


            }
        });
    }


    private void verificaQtdLista() {
        if (produtoList.size() == 0) {
            text_info.setText("Nenhum produto cadastrado.");
            text_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            text_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        text_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    private void iniciaComponentes() {
        ibAdd = findViewById(R.id.ib_add);
        ibVerMais = findViewById(R.id.ib_ver_mais);
        rvProdutos = findViewById(R.id.rvProdutos);
        text_info = findViewById(R.id.text_info);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickListener(Produto produto) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FormProdutoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("produto", produto);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

```
package br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.adapter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.R;
import br.com.hellodev.controledeprodutos.model.Produto;

public class AdapterProduto extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProduto.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Produto> produtoList;
    private OnClick onClick;

    public AdapterProduto(List<Produto> produtoList, OnClick onClick) {
        this.produtoList = produtoList;
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_produto, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Produto produto = produtoList.get(position);

        holder.textProduto.setText(produto.getNome());
        holder.textEstoque.setText("Estoque: " + produto.getEstoque());
        holder.textValor.setText("R$ " + produto.getValor());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> onClick.onClickListener(produto));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return produtoList.size();
    }

    public interface OnClick {
        void onClickListener(Produto produto);
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textProduto, textEstoque, textValor;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textProduto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_produto);
            textEstoque = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_estoque);
            textValor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_valor);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at your code. Find the places where you are calling `setOnClickListener()` using an object of the type `ImageButton`. Look for each `ImageButton` in your code: has it been assigned a value before `setOnClickListener()` is called. If not, why not? One of them is `null`.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, thanks a lot for the tip!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should call `iniciaComponentes()` before `ouvinteCliques()`.

In `iniciaComponentes()` you have the `findViewById()` calls that initialize some of the view items including `ImageButton ibAdd`.

The `ibAdd` object is then accessed in `ouvinteCliques()` with the `setOnClickListener()` call and it can't be null at that point.

Comment: Thanks! Your tip worked, thank you very much :D